# Failed to spawn: unable to find process with name

Tags: apk, patch, frida

1. Here I'm trying to run command `frida-trace <app-package-name>`, getting error

```
Failed to spawn: unable to find process with name '<app-package-name>'
```

2. Tried using pid number too with help of `frida-ps -D <deviceID> -ai`/`frida-ps -Uai`.

```
Failed to attach: unable to find process with pid xxxx
```

3. Also tried with `--attach-pid=xxxx`

```
Failed to attach: unable to act on other processes when embedded
```

Getting this error.
It worked fine on frida 14.2.18, now upgrading to 15.2.2.
Help please.

Answer (score 1):

For calls to `frida-trace` is missing the `-U` parameter. This parameter is necessary because you want to attach to an Android app running on an USB connected device.

Without the `-U` parameter Frida tries to find and attach to a process on your local PC instead of your Android device.

Furthermore when using the Android packageName of an app I would add the `-N` parameter just to make sure Frida doesn't interpret the package name as name

Considering everything I would use the following command:

```
frida-trace -U -N <app-package-name>
```

Comment: Actually I like the way of answer. I need to specify package as a command but `-N` showing error. ```frida: error: unrecognized arguments: -N```. I even tried with `-n`, same error as before ```Failed to spawn: unable to find process with name 'com.an.biometric.sample'```

Comment: @naresh Your Frida version seem to be a bit old. Please update the two python packages `frida` and `frida-tools` to the latest version (16.0.1 at the moment).

Comment: yeah I checked @robert. 16.0.1 is latest version released two weeks before. Checked 16.0.1 also. I already worked on 14.x now checking with 15.x. This error still not got resolved.

Comment: ```Failed to spawn: unable to find process with name 'xxxxx'```

Comment: @naresh Some apps implement anti-debugging measures (like hiding the process). May be the app you want to hook uses something like this? You should name the app and include a frida-ps output. Also make sure frida-server is executed with su.

Comment: now I'm getting this error `Failed to spawn: need Gadget to attach on jailed Android; its default location is: frida\gadget-android-arm64.so`. Any idea?

Comment: @naresh That message means frida-server is not started on the phone. You need to copy frida-server that matches your device cpu e.g to `/data/local/tmp` , make it executable via chmod and then execute it with root permissions.